# Do lexicographers have a formal term for Insta-cant

Tags: slang

With twitter and social media, it is possible for new cant to appear suddenly and spread widely in weeks or days, often via *internet-memes*, only to fall out of use just as quickly. Do lexicographers have a formal term for this insta-cant that distinguishes it from old-school slang?

Comment: Slang has always been mostly ephemeral. I'm not sure there is evidence supporting a qualitative difference in how it works in contemporary society than how it used to work. Probably just yet another example of the recency illusion.

Comment: Much of it is spread not by "word of mouth" but in texts and tweets. Would you consider that a qualitative difference in how it works in contemporary society? I do.

Comment: So is the need for a new name for slang that it's spread by written word rather than spoken word, or that it is fast ("insta-")?

Comment: @nohat: nearly instant spread divorced from the constraints of geography and spoken conversation is the phenomenon. There are some similarities with pre-internet movie-going, but the ubiquity of internet-capable devices like smartphones, coupled with the absence of speech (text only) takes things into a  new realm.

Comment: @TRomano how is the realm new? How is this not just an example of recency illusion? Is there evidence that there is something actually novel going on, or just a minor shift in how trends spread?

Comment: @TRomano I like your term, "insta-cant". Pithy and cute!

Answer (score 3):

A newly coined word or phrase is known as a ***neologism***.

*Neologisms* may or may not fall out of use later, but its newness distinguishes it from "old-school slang".

A ***protologism*** is also a *neologism* which has been coined in the hope that it will catch on in the future.

Alternatively, the perfect term comes from linguistics professor [Geoff Nunberg](http://www.npr.org/2013/12/19/255294091/narcissistic-or-not-selfie-is-nunbergs-word-of-the-year). These words he "likes to think of as ***mayfly words*** — the ones that bubble briefly to the surface in the wake of some fad or fashion."

Comment: If its definition were broadened to include "repeated" (rather than merely "coined"), *protologism* could be used here, yes.

Comment: An apt metaphor for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure one can invent a word (neologisms are words) in the hope that it will become a word (RHK Webster's demands 'a unit of language, consisting of one or more spoken sounds or their written representation, **that functions as a principal carrier of meaning**'; bolding mine). A do-it-yourself string isn't functioning as a principal carrier of meaning unless and until it becomes a neologism.

Comment: Can you add an authority licensing this use of the word protologism? Collins does define it the way you use it, but the term usually has a different meaning. I'm trying to contact Collins about their question-begging 'a word which has not been accepted ... as a word' claim.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protologism) has it, but also notes it's *(chiefly Wiktionary and W[Wiki]M[media]F[Foundation] jargon)*. They list a number of [citations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:protologism#English) from 2005-2011.

Comment: Yes. Calling something that's not been accepted as a word a word is hardly sound scholarship.

Comment: How do you define word acceptance? Use? Dictionary definitions?